# Why I can't delete the data of table in the core data

Tags: swift, core-data

I am doing a sample app: one add button to add the phonenumber from the contacts; when i swipe the row, it will appear delete and I could delete the data in the row and at the same time, the data in the coredata there is also gone.

I did the following code: adding function works well with tableview and core data. But for the delete one, i could delete the data in the tableview but it seems the data is not deleted from the core data. However, it didn't give me an error message. I just don't know what goes wrong and why I could not delete it in the core data.Please help. Thank you.

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext


        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete){

             let item = items[indexPath.row]


                managedContext.deleteObject(item)


                items.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

            tableView.reloadData()

        }
    }





    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        // fetching the contacts from the core data

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Contact")

        do {

          let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
            items = results as! [NSManagedObject]


        } catch {
            print("there is an error")

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to  save your `managedContext` for your changes (delete) to reflect.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete){
         let item = items[indexPath.row]
         managedContext.deleteObject(item)

         do {
             try managedContext.save()
         } catch let error as NSError {
             print("\(error)") 
         }

         items.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
         tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```